# Tcl script to do Indentation

Tags: tcl, indentation

I want to write a tcl script to align my tcl script with proper indentation. For Example if i have a code  like :

```
proc calc { } {
set a 5
set b 10
if {a < b} {
puts "b Greater"
}
}
```

I need to change like:

```
proc calc { } {
    set a 5
    set b 10
    if {a < b} {
        puts "b Greater"
    }
}
```

Could u guys help on this.

Comment: You might want to check out `frink`, it's outdated but it may be OK for you: http://wiki.tcl.tk/2611

Comment: besides `frink` and `naglfar` what does this?  Nobody uses pretty-print of their tcl code?  They just write it pretty all the time??

Answer (score 0):

Writing an indenter that handles your example is trivial. A full indenter that can handle most Tcl scripts is going to be very big and quite complicated. An indenter that can handle any Tcl script will have to incorporate a full Tcl interpreter.

This is because Tcl source code is very dynamic: for one thing you can't always just look at the code and know which parts are executing code and which parts are data. Another thing is user-defined control structures, which might change how the code is to be viewed. The example below works by counting braces, but it makes no attempt to distinguish between quoting braces that should increase indentation and quoted braces that should not.

This example is a very simple indenter. It is *severely limited* and *should not be used* for serious implementations.

```
proc indent code {
    set res {}
    set ind 0
    foreach line [split [string trim $code] \n] {
        set line [string trim $line]
        # find out if the line starts with a closing brace
        set clb [string match \}* $line]
        # indent the line, with one less level if it starts with a closing brace
        append res [string repeat {    } [expr {$ind - $clb}]]$line\n
        # look through the line to find out the indentation level of the next line
        foreach c [split $line {}] {
            if {$c eq "\{"} {incr ind}
            if {$c eq "\}"} {incr ind -1}
        }
    }
    return $res
}
```

This will convert your first code example to your second one. Add even a single brace as data somewhere in the code to be indented, though, and the indentation will be off.

Documentation: [append](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/append.htm), [expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)